# What if you don't bring your credit card or debit for incidentals?

Tags: usa, money, hotels, payment-cards

Usually I never bring my card out, that's what I ask.

Will not bringing my credit or debit card be a problem to a hotel such as The Park Ave North?

Comment: Why not? It's much more complicated to travel with out a Credit Card and a card is also a lot safer (and typically cheaper) then cash.

Comment: Please update your question to include what the comments are asking you to clarify.  If you update the question with more content, people reading the question won't have to read all of the comments just to understand the question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94315/discussion-on-question-by-israel-muboyayi-what-if-you-dont-bring-your-credit-ca).

Comment: Not sure how broad incidentals are, but keep in mind that beyond room service/minibar many hotels will only check the room for damage/surprises after you already left. Hence they have a reasonable argument (process efficiency) to require a card.

Answer (score 29):

Travelling without a credit in the US is difficult.

1. It's almost impossible to rent a car.
2. Some hotels will try to work with you, others will not.
3. You may have to put down substantial amounts of cash as deposit.
4. Many providers will simply refuse service. For example: there is a
   simple food truck outside of Boston's South Station that takes card
   only: no card? no coffee!
5. Large amount of cash are very unusual in the US and may raise suspicion or concerns. Some travel providers may report this to local authorities which may or may not decide to check you out.
6. Somewhat far fetched but still possible: The US has statute called "civil forfeiture" where authorities can take your cash just "on a hunch" and even without any wrongdoing, you have no way of getting it back.

It's NOT recommended.

**EDIT**
Hotels and car rental companies mainly want a credit card or deposit  to cover unexpected expense that you didn't plan on having in the first place: a car accident, getting keyed in the parking lot (happened to me), breaking something in the hotel room, late night snack attack on the mini-bar, etc.

Comment: "no card? no coffee!": there are other places that will sell you some coffee for cash, however.

Comment: @phoog: of course. This was just an example of how you can into a no-cash policy these days, even at places where you wouldn't expect it, such as a food truck.

Comment: The civil asset forfeiture section is a slight exaggeration. It is possible to get the money back. It's just time consuming, expensive, and not a sure thing.

Comment: The litigation may cost more than the money is worth, and, the cops have a well-tuned sense of that....

Comment: @Harper: But they don't have a well-tuned sense of "millions for defense but not one cent for tribute."

Comment: @Hilmar of course. I just wanted to point out that the US hasn't yet reached the point where one will be unable to find competing businesses that do accept cash, at least in my experience (living in the US).

Comment: Please give some sort of citation for point#5.  I have never heard of TRAVEL PROVIDERS recording or reporting anything regarding large amounts of cash.  Border control may question it if you are coming in from another country but once in, I can't see any hotel employee looking into your wallet and reporting to the police that you are rich.

Comment: @Hilmar A food truck is exactly where you would expect a no-cash policy...

Comment: @Keeta: US business are asked to report cash transaction of over $10,000 to the IRS. See https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/irs-form-8300-reference-guide I have seen this happening, although with a travel provider

Comment: @Hilmar Point 1: a DEPOSIT on the hotel stay is not a transaction under this code; it is an escrow payment.  This code specifically exempts travel and entertainment expenses that are charged in incremental payments of this type (daily/weekly, etc from a form of escrow account). (source:former auditor working in my company area) Point 2:the IRS is not a "local authority".  Point 3: In the privacy information act section of this form, it states that its level of reporting is limited to using this information to identify people avoiding income tax.  You are greatly exaggerating in points 5 and 6.

Comment: #4 is a very rare occurrence in the States. Almost all retailers take cash.

Comment: Numbers 1-3 are the main problems.

Comment: @Barmar Most retailers will take cash (though an increasing minority of merchants are beginning to go cashless,) but it will be a much bigger problem at places like hotels, airlines, and rental car agencies, quite a lot of which will not accept cash.

Comment: @reirab Exactly. That's why I said items 1-3 can be actual problems. His example of a cashless food truck is an extreme outlier. In general, if you're buying something whose price is under $100, it would be extremely surprising not to be able to pay with cash.

Comment: @AzorAhai Personally, I would have expected a food truck to *only* take cash (but I've never been to the US)...

Comment: @Deolater IF getting the money back "is not a sure thing", it seems the claim is not exaggerated (when it is already under the "far fetched" caveat)

Comment: No cash? No coffee? — if you’re going to give that example you should also site the counter point: there are plenty of places that take cash only. Only having a card might exclude you from those places, it’s easier to leave a card at a restaurant or have it stolen and be left with no money. The premise that credit card is preferred over cash is somewhat obscene. Cash is king.

Comment: @vol7ron The thing about a debit card, though, is you can use it to get cash. You can't use cash to get a card. And plus, even if it is more likely to have a credit card stolen, you're not responsible for the charges. There is 0% chance of getting your cash back once it's stolen. When traveling, you should definitely always have local currency, but cards, usually at least two in different places are indispensable. Cash is not king in the US.

Comment: A debit card is a bad idea unless you have bad credit and can’t obtain a credit care. Debit cards are directly tied to your money. If your account is compromised you are risking not getting some of the money back. Credit is on the credit issuer and they are more likely to reimburse the amount of stolen credit. Also, yes credit is easy to travel with, but you should have contingency plans. Cash is king in the US - that’s where the phrase comes from. Most businesses prefer it. It’s a sure transaction, whereas a credit transaction can be frozen by a customer and a business may lose out.

Answer (score 18):

When you check-in, a card is usually requested, which will be used as a guarantee for incidentals, but also in some cases for the cost of the hotel itself (unless you paid at tile of booking, of course).

- Some hotels will simply not accept anything else.
- Others will just block any incidentals on your room. That may include locking the mini-bar if there is one, blocking external calls, pay per view, etc, flagging the room for room service, bars, restaurants, etc. so they refuse to charge your room, and so on. Depending on the hotel, this may be very easy (if there are no stocked minibars anyway, no bar or restaurant, etc.) or not.
- Others still will ask for a cash deposit instead. Depending on the hotel, it could range from a few dozen USD to hundreds.

Of course, if they also need to charge for the room, there will be no choice but paying in advance or leaving a deposit.

Note that **even if you provided your card when you booked, you may still be asked to present the card**, as you are switching from the "Card Not Present" regime (used to charge the penalty in case of no show) to the "Card Present" mode. They want to make sure they see the card, and either swipe it or have you use your PIN.

In any case, what exactly happens and what options are available is very dependent on the hotel's policies, so your best bet is simply to call them.

Answer (score 7):

Credit Card not REQUIRED for this hotel

According to website [Hotels.com](https://www.hotels.com/ho571541/the-park-ave-north-new-york-united-states-of-america/):

> Required at check-in
>
> .  .  .Credit card or cash deposit required
>
> .  .  .Government-issued photo ID required
>
> .  .  .Minimum check-in age is 18

It does not specify what the cash deposit is, and is likely tied to the length of your stay (you may need to deposit more than the total bill would be at checkout).